# Search DirContext without name

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I use a service account to connect to Active Directory and then search for a user using the context like :

```
String searchBase = "DC=extLDAP,DC=com";
String query = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=batty))";
final SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();

final NamingEnumeration<?> searchResults = dirContext.search(searchBase,searchQuery,constraints);
```

But I have a scenario when searchBase is not given to me. In this case, I need to search through complete active directory.

I tried to use `searchBase=null;` and `searchBase="";` but in both cases I get `NullPointerException` and `NameNotFoundException` respectively.

Is there any way I can search through complete active directory without knowing `searchBase` or domain name.

***Note***: I am making connection using **full dn** of service account. So, not knowing domain name specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The searchbase is always the domain root `DC=extLDAP,DC=com` - you cannot search more objects in your AD.

However, if you do not know the domain root context beforehand, you can do either of three things:

- resolve the domain root context using a query of the rootDSE object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- use AD's *phantom root* option to search the entire domain without specifying the context: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366988.aspx
- resolve the domain details using DNS: [How can I find out which server hosts LDAP on my windows domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749268/how-can-i-find-out-which-server-hosts-ldap-on-my-windows-domain)

Of course all Microsoft examples are in C# or worse, but you should be able to translate to proper Java.